# ASP.NET 4 MetaKeywords and MetaDescription being Encoded

Tags: asp.net, encoding, seo, antixsslibrary

I'm using the ASP.NET 4 `MetaKeywords` and `MetaDescription` on every page to set the appropriate meta tags. I also use the Anti XSS Library as the default encoder in the application.

The tags end up being rendered like:

```
<meta name="description" content="Test&#32;description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="my&#32;meta,&#32;tags,&#32;encoded,&#32;why" />
```

The `AntiXssLibrary` is set to default in `web.config` as below:

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="AntiXssEncoder, MyClassLib"/>
```

Is there an issue with them being encoded this way, and is there any way I can get rid of this encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't cause a problem - the encoding is correct. I don't know of any web crawlers that won't understand it. You can't get rid of it I'm afraid - what's happening there is that HtmlAttributeEncoding is being called, and that's designed to be safe for name/id fields, where spaces should be encoded. AntiXSS is a bit stricter than the default ASP.NET encoders by design.